# How to use same session for https://example.com to https://www.example.com?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-cookies

I have a domain as https://example.com When i logged in then have serverl links comming in site that inclueds the https://www.example.com. When i clicked that link then the current session will not continue and it redirect to the registration page.

Is there any way to use the same session with https://example.com and https://www.example.com.

I know one solution is to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com.
This will solve but is there any other way that we can use the same session for both urls?

Answer (score 0):

This arises due to cookies being tied to the domain they are set on. Try the following.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Domain = ".example.com";
});
```

The dot in example.com specifies that cookies are available across subdomains.